# Are Android game apps open sourced by Google?

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, game-engine

I am working on my current game app and I am not using any of the game engine platform. I code the game in Java and think to publish for Android devices(because the registration fee is very low as you all know). But in the part of the game I have a logic error. I have been researching it, unfortunately I haven't found any solid answer about it.

I saw a game in Google play and some of the game features are very similar the thing that I try to implement to my codes. Is there any chance to see the codes of that game?(I am sure that is sort of impossible because of the copyrights.) Or does Google allow the developer to see the codes like an open-source?

My other question is if those game engine platforms are worthy to pay over $1500 or not?(e.g UNITY).
The reason I am asking this if I can not solve this logic error, It seems like it is going to be easier for me to pay and get one of those game engines. Thanks for your time and attention.

Answer (score 0):

Their work is copyrighted. [See here](http://developer.android.com/distribute/googleplay/policies/ip.html)

However, you may want to try contacting the developer and see if they would help you out with your issues.